# Basic setup of LAMP with CentOS. Why won't Zend Framework's Router will work?

Tags: php, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, routes

So I have a basic web server setup with a LAMP stack on CentOS. It has mod_rewrite and all the basic modules. The routing I have used is working on other servers and locally. But when I try to use the routes on the new server they give me a 404 error. Now the kicker is that the regular default routes work (i.e. /index/my-page works but the special route /my-page does not on this server) so I know mod-rewrite is firing correctly. Also, there are no actual files with the route names so there is no conflict there.

My guess is something is not configured right for the router being I have done this before the same way and had no problem. I am wondering if anyone knows any potential little things that the router may need to run that I might have missed.

Thank you for any insight.

**UPDATE: Here are the Rewrite htaccess entries I have tried**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

and (from another Dev I work with)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Here is the routes.xml aside from the extra markup for enviroments:

```
    <routes>
        <home>
            <route>/home</route>
            <defaults>
                <controller>index</controller>
                <action>index</action>
            </defaults>
        </home>
        <lifetime-solutions-annuity>
            <route>/lifetime-solutions-annuity</route>
            <defaults>
                <controller>index</controller>
                <action>lifetime-solutions-annuity</action>
            </defaults>
        </lifetime-solutions-annuity>
        <indexed-universal-life>
            <route>/indexed-universal-life</route>
            <defaults>
                <controller>index</controller>
                <action>indexed-universal-life</action>
            </defaults>
        </indexed-universal-life>
        <wellness-for-life>
            <route>/wellness-for-life</route>
            <defaults>
                <controller>index</controller>
                <action>wellness-for-life</action>
            </defaults>
        </wellness-for-life>
        <join>
            <route>/join</route>
            <defaults>
                <controller>index</controller>
                <action>join</action>
            </defaults>
        </join>

    </routes>
```

Comment: This does *not* belong on ServerFault, as the routing issue *might* be with the routing rules in ZF, which is most certainly not a server configuration issue.  @gokujou, can you show us your `.htaccess` and all of your routing rules, please?

Comment: I have added them above. I about 80% sure this is an issue with ZF more than the server, but the server could be a possibility.

Comment: What version of PHP do you have? I, on CentOS 5.5 have PHP 5.1.6 which is far below required PHP 5.2.4 for ZF 1.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that AllowOverride All or at least AllowOverride FileInfo has been set? It sounds like Apache is ignoring the .htaccess file.

Comment: But then why would the default routing for ZF still work? That still uses the rewrite.

Comment: This worked, I would have thought being the default routes worked I had set all the settings I needed. Didn't notice I forgot to set the AllowOverride when I setup the server. Thanks.